# How to access private variable in different class Java

Tags: java, class, private

I have one class, SpellCheck, that (along with a variety of other things) creates a trie from the file name given in the Interactions window. When I enter     java SpellCheck small.txt   for example, I know that a Lexicon/dictionary is created because it's displayed by other methods in SpellCheck.

```
public class SpellCheck{

 // the dictionary

 private LexiconTrie dict;


 // Constructor;  creates window elements

 public SpellCheck(String[] files) {

  dict = new LexiconTrie(files);
```

I need to access the information in that LexiconTrie     dict     (iteration, roots, nodes, etc.) in my other class LexiconTrie. However, whenever I try to access it (even when using     SpellCheck.dict    it gives me the error of "dict has private access in SpellCheck" (or something along those lines).

Am I not fully understanding the private/public class interaction in this case? (Please let me know if I have not given enough information)
---------EDIT/UPDATE---------------------

This is the method in SpellCheck

```
public void doAutoComplete() {
  Collection<String> arr = dict.getCompletions(curText.trim().toLowerCase(), num_value);
  String intro = "Up to " + num_value + " completions";
  display(arr, "No matches found", intro);   
}
```

I need to write the method `getCompletions()` in LexiconTrie. My professor has implemented a GUI interface for us. This GUI interface creates a search bar that calls `doAutoComplete` whenever the user types a letter into the search bar. In LexiconTrie, I am supposed to write `getCompletions` to return matches("completions") found in `LexiconTrie dict`(which is created and stored privately in SpellCheck).

I saw that as writing the method along these lines:

```
// Method you have to implement
public Collection<String> getCompletions(String lowerCase, int max) {
  String searchWord = lowerCase;
  int maxReturned = max;
  LinkedList trieMatches = new LinkedList();


  // this is as far as I got, it won't even print the search word. 
 // I get an error from trying to look into dict with .containsWord
  if (dict.containsWord(searchWord)){
    System.out.println(searchWord); 
    //add word/prefix to LinkedList
    //add all children and their children up until max#
  }

  else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `private` fields are private. They cannot be accessed outside of the class. That's exactly what private is for.

Comment: I think you are indeed not understanding private/public.. Private members can only be accessed inside their own class.

Comment: Provide some kind of `public` accessor/getter for it in the `SpellCheck` class

Comment: You need to read about Access Modifiers check this out. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: I asked my professor this question, with the same bewilderment that I _couldn't_ access a private variable outside of its class, and she responded with an example of accessing a private variable within its own class **infuriating** I thought I understood private/public but my professor didn't even blink at my issue with accessing the `private LexiconTrie dict` from a different class. Also, I can't edit SpellCheck...

Comment: I'm not really following you.  I gather that you're supposed to write `LexiconTrie`?  A `LexiconTrie` will have its own private variables and private and public methods, and the methods in the `LexiconTrie` can access them directly, using `this.field` or usually just `field`.  There should be no reason for your `LexiconTrie` to look at anything in `SpellCheck`, or even to know that such a thing as a `SpellCheck` exists.

Comment: If the field is private, and you can't modify the class it's contained in, you can't do anything. It can only be accessed within that class, and none other. If you have getter/setters use those, if not, give up.

Comment: @katev As Thilo said, the *entire point* of `private` is that it stops you from accessing the field outside the same class. Of course you can't access it from outside the same class. If you wanted to do that, you wouldn't use `private`. It's like locking your front door, then complaining you can't open it.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm so frustrated. My professor gave us the code for SpellCheck and the code for LexiconTrie. The LexiconTrie is created, but I need to write a method in LexiconTrie that displays the results of the dict (created in SpellCheck) when SpellCheck calls it. I'm going to edit my question to add more details to hopefully clarify, because apparently I'm missing something if my professor set it all up for us

Answer (score 1):

> I need to access the information in that LexiconTrie dict (iteration, roots, nodes, etc.) in my other class LexiconTrie.

That seems weird (hard to tell without seeing more code, though).

Normally instead of accessing another instance of LexiconTrie, you would want to operate on `this`.

So instead of

```
void someMethod(SpellCheck spellCheck){
    spellCheck.dict.something();
}
```

you would have

```
void someMethod(){
    something();
}
// called from spellcheck as
this.dict.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

create a method for accessing the private variable:

```
public LexiconTrie getDict(){
  return dict;
}
```